# What are the supported versions of JPA does EclipseLink 2.5 support

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0, eclipselink, glassfish-3

I am trying to use EclipseLink 2.5 in my GlassFish 3.1.2.2 but it seems that its not working properly.

So What are the supported versions of JPA does EclipseLink 2.5 support ?
I am restricted to use JPA 2.0 till the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EclipseLink 2.5 is implementation of JPA 2.1 specification. Because JPA 2.1 ([what's new](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/What_is_new_in_JPA_2.1?)) is more or less superset of JPA 2.0, it is possible to use EclipseLink 2.5 and limit usage to features available in JPA 2.0.

GlassFish 3.1.2.2 was shipped with EclipseLink 2.3.2 (which is implementation of JPA 2 specification), so it is rather easy try is EclipseLink version source of problems. Likely not - but new bugs are of course always possible. Also then issue is not directly connected to supported JPA specification version.

Comment: +1 for " it is possible to use EclipseLink 2.5 and limit usage to features available in JPA 2.0".
I have updated EclipseLink libs to the latest version that support JPA 2 which is version 2.4.2 and it works correctly till the moment